# How can I give style all td tags in a tr tag via jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to give style to the cells in specific table rows via jQuery.

The catch is that I need to check an attribute row by row and if I found something I expect, the row **BEFORE** the current one should be re-styled.

I'm using the following code but instead of draw the border only for the cells of the row, it draws it for every cell in the table:

```
$(".some_class_for_every_row_in_the_table").each(function() {
    var control_variable = ... //This is the attribute
    if (control_variable) {
        $(previous_row).find('td').each(function() {$(this).css('border-bottom', "1px solid #AAAAAA")});
    }
    previous_row = this; 
...
})
```

This is the HTML of the table:

```
<table>
    ...
    <tbody>
        <tr control_variable="...">
          <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr control_variable="...">
          <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        ...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The `control_variable` is gotten with the correct value and previous_row maintains consistency at all times.

I'm sorry if I mis leaded with the first version of the question.

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: `$(this).find('td').css('border-bottom', "1px solid #AAAAAA");` or `$(".some_class_for_rows td").css('border-bottom', "1px solid #AAAAAA");`
`

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thank you, but I already tried that. Same result.

Comment: Well, guess what? You're about to get a bunch of those type of responses. You need a complete question with the markup too.

Comment: Could you please show the HTML, I believe the issue is you have the class 'some_class_for_rows' on every tr in the table - and the 'each' would target them all.

Comment: And again you've ignored the requests to ***show your HTML***. Please, it would be very helpful. Also, what attribute are you checking? Are you checking that it's there, that it's equal to a value, that it begins with, ends with or contains a value..?

Comment: this is still over simplified html, there are no classes shown. Provide enough valid html that replicates your problem with the code you are using. Shouldn't have to guess which level of nesting your classes are on, or what test to use for `control_variable` or what rows need css changes

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you're not simply using:

```
$('.some_class_for_rows td').css('border-bottom','1px solid #aaa');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3bZcS/).

Another guess at what you're trying to do, since you've so far only posted something approaching pseudo-code, in the following example, we're iterating over *every* `tr` element, assessing it for the attribute `data-controlVariable` and, if present, adding the class `rowBeforeControlVariable` to the previous row:

```
$('tr').each(
    function(i){
        if ($(this).attr('data-controlVariable')){
            $('tr:eq(' + (i-1) + ')').addClass('rowBeforeControlVariable');
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3bZcS/1/).

Comment: No, the OP said he tried the code in his question; which is not the code in my answer (which works, according to the linked JS Fiddle).

Comment: His comment under mine under the question?

Comment: Ah! I hadn't seen the comments (I hadn't loaded until just after I responded). Also, seeing as that information wasn't in the question it seems a little odd to be penalised for not knowing what he'd already tried.

Comment: Yes, there is. Actually, I think I oversimplified the code and the answer is in what I left out. I'm fairly new to this site, should I ask another question or edit this one?

Comment: @DanielCalderonMori - Edit this one.

Comment: @DanielCalderonMori: please, edit this question; include what you've already tried and the relevant HTML. Also, if possible, post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can try and see what's going wrong. My demo works, so something else must be happening in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
$(".some_class_for_rows").each(function() { 
    $('td', this).css('border-bottom', "1px solid #AAAAAA");
})​;
```

Should work

http://jsfiddle.net/NwWkk/

Comment: That's a novel approach; I think that might be slow(er). You could condense it into one statement...

Comment: @JaredFarrish using find() is surely slower than using a context, but in the end david solution is better

Comment: I know, it's the same I had in my comment. It's also "not working" vis a vis the OP.

Comment: @JaredFarrish then there must be an error in his HTML because the fiddle is working :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table tr[control_variable=VALUE]").prev("tr").find("td").css( ... set your attribute ...);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/cranio/MvVgS/1/

This works for fixed values of the control variable. If they vary, you should resort to "`.each()`".

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the markup it's hard to tell, but I would say you probably have the same class 'some_class_for_rows' on each row in the table.

```
<table>
  <tr class="some_class_for_rows">
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="some_class_for_rows">
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For just a single row, you would need something unique to target, e.g.:

```
<table>
  <tr class="some_class_for_rows selected">
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="some_class_for_rows">
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then use the following code:

```
$('.some_class_for_rows.selected td').css('border-bottom','1px solid #aaa');
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt get clear idea about your code.. But try this code... using 'each' makes us confused sometimes.....

If you are having same class name for all 'tr', this will help.

```
var len=$('.some_class_for_rows').length;
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
 var control_variable = ... //This is the attribute
 if (control_variable)
{
 $('.some_class_for_rows').eq(i).prev('tr').find('td').
 css('border-bottom', "1px solid #AAAAAA");
}
}
```